# Yii2 display file listing instead of execute project

Tags: url, yii2

I am new in `Yii2` and execute project then display `file listing` instead of execute it self.

I put URl upto `http://localhost/projectname/frontend/web`  but display listing in browsers.

What exactly issue did not found. Any one have a `idea or suggestions.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you install the application, run the php init file with this command:

> php init

more reference:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=5

Comment: Actually client existing project so just download and then try to run it.

Comment: I run 'php init' and works fine. Great. Thanks buddy.